# Is it correct to use "and" immediately followed by "or" or "or" immediately followed by "and"?

Tags: conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is using “and/or” recommended for formal writing, or is it frowned upon?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21115/is-using-and-or-recommended-for-formal-writing-or-is-it-frowned-upon)
>   [Alternatives to “and/or”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/alternatives-to-and-or)

Is it correct to use *and* immediately followed by *or*, or *or* immediately followed by *and* as in the following examples?

- You can use x and or y.
- You can use x or and y.

The meaning I want to say in the given examples is "You can use x or y or both".

Comment: I smell a duplicate. I will delete this soon. What do you think?

Comment: @karthik:I am confused in whether I have to accept karthik's answer or ErikE's answer or both. :-)

Comment: Now, that you have chosen the right one, I cannot provide a solution to your confusion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in written context you can use **or/and**, which should be fine.

In spoken context, it is usually understood from the context if both would be meant to be included or not eg. Tom wanted to marry Stella or Mary. We would assume, here, both is not meant. :-)

Knowing a European language, French or German may be helpful, if you plan to go on a trip to the Alps. Surely, here, knowing both wont hurt, if knowing one helps!

Usually only 'or' suffices to mean both as well, since in usual common sense and boolean logic 'or' is just that: either of the two or both. This is why the term ex-or (exclusively 'or') was invented to mean: either of the two, but not both.

Comment: Which one do you prefer `and/or` or `or/and` or both? :-) Of course +1 for you.

Comment: For your purpose, or/and should work. I can tell a particular context where and/or is more appropriate. "blah-blah is a punishable offence under law with a maximum of 3 months of rigorous imprisonment and/or a fine up to 100 <currency unit>". Here, the emphasis on **and** before or, puts an extra seriousness. ;)

Comment: [*And/or* is more common than *or/and* nowadays](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+or%2Cor+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but they’ve both enjoyed a long history in common use.

Comment: got some nice curves: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+or%2Cor+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+or%2Cor+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+or%2Cor+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3 http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+or%2Cor+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3

Comment: @JonPurdy What do you think about the curves? Even more interesting is this one: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+or%2Cor+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=11&smoothing=3

Comment: @karthik What's the value of German, French, and Chinese here?

Comment: @ErikE I was trying to say that the nGram makes mistakes, so one should be careful.

Comment: 'or/and' is not used at all nowadays in AmE writing. Neither 'and/or' nor 'or/and' is used in spoken AmE.

Answer (score 2):

Using *and/or* is in my opinion redundant and awkward. If you want to stress that both may be chosen, say, "do you want X or Y or both?" In most cases, *or* is not required to be mutually exclusive, so there is no need to emphasize it. "Do you want pizza or a hot dog?" always leaves open the answer "both," or even the humorous answer "yes" (meaning the same thing).

To clearly denote that both cannot be chosen, you would use *either/or*: "You may choose either X or Y." Also, "which one: X or Y?" or "choose only one of X and Y." The respondent can still say "both".

If you insist on using *and/or*, it takes a slash, not a space. Using two conjunctions in a row doesn't makes sense. It's as awkward and incorrect as "You must could do this." Yikes!

Note that *or/and* has fallen into disuse in the last 30 years and many people will find it strange.