# Is there a single word for the conjunction "and/or"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, grammar, conjunctions, and-or

For example:

"Would you like to eat a pizza and/or a hamburger"

Comment: Relate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30254

Comment: That is a strange offer, asking if someone would like to eat a pizza **and** a hamburger. I suppose it is possible... but I think a more plausible offer/invite/ is needed here, e.g "Have dessert and/or a coffee". Here you have three options: a) only dessert b) dessert and coffee c) only coffee.

Comment: @Susan *If **there** was*, we are on an English language Q&A!

Comment: @Kris obviously a typo, happens to the best of us.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not a typo. Many do the switch.

Answer (score -1):

You have two good choices. If you're speaking, you can make the "or" likely to be understood as inclusive by speaking it weakly, almost running "pizza or hamburger" together. Alternatively, you can add "or both" on the end.