# Can "either" mean both "any" and "both"

Tags: meaning

I was checking out the definition of *either* in dictionary, here is what I found:

> one or the other of two things (any of the things will be fine)
>
> one and the other of two things (either side of the road)

so, the word "either" can basically mean both *any* or *both*, is that right?

Let's say I want to say:

> Either of these options will do (any of the two options will do)

Can it also mean both of the options will do?

Comment: It likely depends on what the options are (in other words, the context). If someone asked me, "I'm going to the deli; what should I get for you for lunch?" and I replied, "Either a ham and cheese, or a roast beef," that person could probably bring me back **two** sandwiches without violating any dictionary definitions or grammatical rules, but I doubt that's what I had in mind when I used the word "either."

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/alternatives-to-and-or

Comment: Be a bit more lucid.Use more illustrations to dispel confusion.What's the meaning of 'either' in instance like 'You don't know him, do you?I don't either'.

Comment: Note that *either* has two common pronunciations.  For many of us who normally say EEE-there for the "any" case it's common to say EYE-there for the "both" case -- "There were potted plants on EYE-there side of the door."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that’s right.  In general, it turns out that sometimes *either* is **distributive**, essentially meaning *both* or *all*, and sometimes it is **exclusionary** and so applies to just one out of the set.

Your question is whether it would be understood to mean just one or if it would mean two in the sentence:

> Either of these options will do.

The answer is that here it means that just one option suffices.  It means “any single option”. If you have any doubts about how it will be received, you can always write *any one option* or some such.

For the most part, I think the “each one” or “both” sense applies to natural pairs.  Here are some OED citations for the “both” kind of *either*:

> - 1762 Falconer *Shipwr. Proem* 40 ― The fierce extremes of either zone.
> - 1820 Scott *Ivanhoe* iii, ― There was a huge fireplace at either end of the hall.
> - 1842 Tennyson *E. Morris* 37 ― Either twilight and the day between.

Note that *either* meaning “both” is the oldest of the various senses the word has come to mean historically.  It is somewhat uncommon these days, but by no means wholly obsolete.

Comment: *Either* in your citations actually means 'each' not 'both'; otherwise you would have one fireplace in two locations. I haven't put this in an answer for fear of confusing OP; but the dictionary that gave 'both' was careless, to say the least.

Comment: @TimLymington Are not “each of the two” and “both” the same?

Comment: No. In a one-way street, you can drive on either side, or each side; but I've never met anyone who can drive on both sides.

Comment: @TimLymington Odd, those are completely interchangeable for me.

Comment: Both sides of the road at once??

Comment: @TimLymington Who said anything about simultaneity? You can drive on either side of the road and you can drive on both sides of the road are completely interchangeable to me.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, although one side might be considerably safer than the other.

Comment: XOR (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/XOR) is nice when you need to be specific about which possibilities are acceptable, but the term hasn't made it into common parlance yet.

Comment: @TimLymington “He wore a ring on the fourth finger of either hand” and “He wore a ring on the fourth finger of both hands” surely mean the same thing, right?  You are not going to try to argue that it is the same ring, I hope, or that the finger is shared between the two hands.

Comment: “He wore a ring on the fourth finger of **each** hand” -- not **a ring on both** hands -- he would not have been able to work, tied up that way.

Answer (score 6):

"Either" and "Both" have strikingly similar definitions (in at least one of their definitions):

> either : being the one and the other of two
>
> both : the one as well as the other

However, "both" often has a context of *at the same time*, whereas "either" often has a context of *one at a time*.   So there are certainly times when they are not interchangeable.  For instance:

> I'd like either an apple or an orange.
>
> I'd like both an apple and an orange.

But there are also times where they *are* interchangeable:

> Bob plays both instruments well.
>
> Bob plays either instrument well.

It all depends on context.

Answer (score 0):

Some print organizations have style guides that require expressions like "on either side of the door" to mean on one side or the other, but not both sides. "There were lions on either side of the door" would be regarded as incorrect. The preferred form would be, "There were lions on each side of the door."

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you cited the style guides you refer to.